# not able to understand how HTTP request handler function is able to access to application object in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I am reading the Introduction to Tornado book, following is the example where author explains how to read a mongodb database.

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web

import pymongo

from tornado.options import define, options
define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [(r"/(\w+)", WordHandler)]
        conn = pymongo.Connection("localhost", 27017)
        self.db = conn["example"]
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, debug=True)

class WordHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, word):
        coll = self.application.db.words
        word_doc = coll.find_one({"word": word})
        if word_doc:
            del word_doc["_id"]
            self.write(word_doc)
        else:
            self.set_status(404)
            self.write({"error": "word not found"})

def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I understand the code and how it works, but I am not able to understand one thing. The WordHandler class' instance is able to access Application class instance. This is what I am not able to understand. Following is the line in WordHandler function :

```
coll = self.application.db.words
```

The object is not passed to it and except that line, nowhere 'application' appears on code. Then how it is able to access it? How the tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer, WordHandler and Application are linked together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything at all about Tornado, but I would suppose that the framework takes care of instantiating the handlers, and passes the application to them when it does so.

In fact you can see this in the code: `Application.__call__()` finds the handler that matches the URL, and instantiates it [like this](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/web.py#L1643):

```
handler = spec.handler_class(self, request, **spec.kwargs)
```

so the application - ie `self`, because we're in a method of Application - is passed as an argument to the RequestHandler instantiation. And in the handler `__init__` we see [this](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/web.py#L122):

```
def __init__(self, application, request, **kwargs):
    super(RequestHandler, self).__init__()

    self.application = application
```